# Logging output or assigned variables within a javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I'm trying to log some variables within functions outside the function, but in js variables in a function are scoped with that particular function and not global, so I can't really use those variables.

As you can see in the code snipplet below I have a function and callback for that function, and what I'm trying to log is within the if statement at the bottom of the code. The result of the console.log turns out to be undefined.

Is there a simple way to externalize the variables within the function?

Thank you so much in advanced.

```
var xml;
var nodelist;
var callLDAP = function (username, callback) {
    var LDAPOptions = {
        "LDAPOptions" : {
            "filter" : {
                "$" : filter
            }
        }
    }
    var options = {};
    options.location = "callLDAP.xsl";
    var xml = converter.toXML('badgerfish', LDAPOptions);
    options.xmldom = XML.parse(XML.stringify(xml));
    transform.xslt(options, function (err, nodelist, abortinfo) {
        if (err) {
            session.out.write(err);
        } else {
            callback(err, converter.toJSON('badgerfish', nodelist.item(0)));
        }
    });
    return xml;
};

var node;
var ldap_response = callLDAP(username, function (error, node) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error @ldapResponse");
        } else {
            return node;
        }
    }
);

if (user == 'debugMode'){
    console.debug("***NODE: " + node);
    console.debug("***nodelist: " + XML.stringify(nodelist.item(0)));
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious way would be to declare your variables outside the function that way they share the parent scope. For example say you have this code:

```
function foo() {
  var bar = 1;
}

foo();
console.log(bar); // error - bar is not defined
```

Instead just do the following:

```
var bar;
function foo() {
  bar = 1;
}

foo();
console.log(bar); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Damon.
That was a part of the answer... I had originally done that, but had continuously gotten undefined, and that was because I was declaring it in the function rather than the callback, and defining the variable within the function and not the callback itself, does not pick up the result of the callback.
In addition, I accidentally declared another 'var' syntax within the function value, which creates another variable rather than using the global variable.

```
function callLDAP (username, callback) {
    var LDAPOptions = {
        "LDAPOptions" : {
            "filter" : {
                "$" : filter
            }
        }
    }
    var options = {};
    options.location = "callLDAP.xsl";
    var xml = converter.toXML('badgerfish', LDAPOptions);
    options.xmldom = XML.parse(XML.stringify(xml));
    transform.xslt(options, function (err, nodelist, abortinfo) {
        if (err) {
            session.out.write(err);
        } else {
            callback(err, converter.toJSON('badgerfish', nodelist.item(0)));
        }
    });
};

var node_results;
callLDAP(username, function (error, node) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error @ldapResponse");
        } else {
            node_results = node;
        }
    }
);

if (user == 'debugMode'){
    console.debug("***NODE_Results: " + node_results);
}; //should output the results from the function call.
```

Thank you.

Comment: glad you got it working, the more code you have the easier it is to get tripped up :)